# Is there a way to change the color of the emissive object without changing the color and strength of the light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, color, emission

So I have this scene

[image]

and I very much like the amount of light and its color on everything inside the room, but the windows are way lighter than i want them to be. But if I change the strength of the emission (now it is at 4) everything gets darker and if i change the color of the emission to simulate darker light, but the whole scene just gets yellow.

I wonder if there is a way to bypass this problem? Maybe to fake emission with an outside light source or to change the initial color of the object without changing the emission color?

Comment: You could create a light to keep the stregth that you want?

Comment: @moonboots yeah that's what i did and it works

Answer (score 2):

Guess I answered the question myself

[image]

I made the emissive objects transparent for the light (pic below) and backlit them with an outside light source

[image]

Comment: Glad you found it! After a bit you'll be able to accept your own answer by ticking it, and that will mark it as solved.